# how can I do health check for cnosdb in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, cnosdb

how can I do health check for cnosdb in kubernetes, as we know, health-check is important in kubernetes, as common, a binary should provider a restful api for kubernetes periodically health-checking. Does cnosdb provider such api?

best practise to do health-checking in kubernetes for cnosdb

Comment: What is `cnosdb` representing on your cluster? A deployment, a service kind, etc..?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very general question, which in my opinion leaves too much room for interpretation.

In general, however, you should think about configuring a Monitoring stack, perhaps based on Prometheus, Grafana and Alertmanager that allows you to extrapolate the metrics that are exposed by the DB.

Otherwise you can do something very rough by following the following CURL:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:21001/metrics
curl http://127.0.0.1:21002/metrics
curl http://127.0.0.1:21003/metrics
```

https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/cluster/cluster.html#meta-custer-startup-process